# Vapor (SwiftNIO) Interfacing with Async Methods

Tags: swift, event-loop, vapor, swift-nio

I am trying to use an async method from a 3rd party library to get a string result from a URL

```
public static func fetch(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
```

inside a Vapor Swift request handler.

```
func getHandler(_ req: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<String> {}
```

Apple's [SwiftNIO documentation](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/1.14.1/NIO/Structs/EventLoopPromise.html) introduces this:

```
func someAsyncOperation(args) -> EventLoopFuture<ResultType> {
    let promise = eventLoop.newPromise(of: ResultType.self)
    someAsyncOperationWithACallback(args) { result -> Void in
        // when finished...
        promise.succeed(result: result)
        // if error...
        promise.fail(error: error)
    }
    return promise.futureResult
}
```

But

> the future result is returned before the async process has provided a value

How do we only return the promise only after it has value?

Answer (score 1):

You were looking at a super old NIO version. You can just write `promise.completeWith(result)`.

See the newer docs at https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIOCore/Structs/EventLoopPromise.html#/s:7NIOCore16EventLoopPromiseV12completeWithyys6ResultOyxs5Error_pGF